# Display image outside html element with CSS

Tags: css

is it possible to display an image outside of textbox with CSS only?

Please see my example below:

[image]

Comment: Am I the only one not being able to open the image in 100% zoom? Have you forgot to provide a link to the full image?

Comment: Sorry, it *is* the full sized image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, with CSS2 it is completely possible (although it is not supported by IE):

```
input.test:before
{
   padding: 4px;
   content: url(images/your_image.gif);
}
```

For more info, check out the following links:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html

If you want something that works in IE as well, you will have to do it with javascript, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of the `label` element? i.e:

```
<style>
.required { padding-right: 20px; background: url(...) no-repeat 50% 100%; }
</style>
<label class="required" title="This is a required field"><dfn>My Field:</dfn> <input type="text" /></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container:

CSS

```
#field-container
{
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: transparent url(images/dot.gif) middle right no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="field-container" class="form-row">
 <label for="field">Field:</label>
 <input type="text" value="" id="field" name="field" />
</div>
```